# Unable to send ERC1155 to a Safe wallet on Polygon

Tags: gnosis-safe, erc-1155

I'm trying to send an ERC1155 to a Safe Wallet from an EOA address, and so far, I have been unsuccessful. Here's the code I'm using:

```typescript
async function main() {
  try {
    // setup
    const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, providerURL)
    const web3 = new Web3(provider)
    const abi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(abipath).toString())
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi.abi, contractAddress)

    // get gas estimate
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
    const estimatedGas = await contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(
      fromAddress,
      toAddress,
      tokenId,
      2,
      '0x'
    )
      .estimateGas({ from: fromAddress })

    logger.debug(`gasPrice ${gasPrice} estimatedGas ${estimatedGas}`)

    // initiate transfer
    const sendResult = await contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(
      fromAddress,
      toAddress,
      tokenId,
      2,
      '0x'
    )
      .send({ from: fromAddress, gas: estimatedGas, gasPrice: gasPrice })

    logger.info(`sendResult ${JSON.stringify(sendResult, null, 2)}`)
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(`error ${e} \n\n ${JSON.stringify(e, null, 2)}`, e)
  }
}
```

I get this error from the `estimateGas` line:

```
 {
  "code": -32000,
  "message": "execution reverted"
} { code: -32000, message: 'execution reverted' }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You sure you are using the correct contract and ABI? Maybe post them here